# How to apply a function to each element of a deque?

Tags: c++, deque

I have an `std::deque<float> k{3, 4, 5, 0};`.

How do I apply a function to each element?

```
float o(float k) {if (k > 4) return k - CONSTDIFF;};
```

After applying this function to each element, the result would be:

```
k == {3, 4, 5-CONSTDIFF, 0};
```

Comment: Please be a little more clear in future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `std::transform` and a lambda expression:

```
std::transform(
    k.begin(),
    k.end(),
    k.begin(),
    [](float f) { 
        return (f > 4.0f) ? (f - CONSTDIFF) : f;
    }
);
```

This is a C++11 solution. You could move that lambda expression to a free function if you're using C++03.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for_each()` to do that.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
float CONSTDIFF=1;
void o(float& k) {if (k > 4) k-= CONSTDIFF;};

int main()
{
    deque<float> k;
    k.push_back(3);
    k.push_back(4);
    k.push_back(5);
    k.push_back(0);


    for_each(k.begin(),k.end(),o);


    for(deque<float>::iterator i=k.begin(); i!=k.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for_each(k.begin(),k.end(),[=](float x)
            {return x>4.0f ? x-CONSTDIFF : x ;});
```

And this?

```
for(auto&x:k) if (x>4) x-=CONSTDIFF;
```